# Is there a way to create a binding off a computed array property in an enum at a particular index in SwiftUI?

Tags: binding, swiftui

I'm modelling view state in my viewModel using an enum...

```
enum ViewState<T> {
    case idle
    case error(Error)
    case loading
    case data([T])
```

I have a computed property to get the data

```
var data: [T] {
   guard case let .data(data) = self else {
      return []
   }
   return data
}
```

In one of my views I iterate through the data

```
var dropdownListView: some View {
   ForEach(viewModel.state.data.indices, id: \.self) { index in
        DropdownView(
                viewModel: $viewModel.state.data[index],
                isActionSheetPresented: $viewModel.isActionSheetPresented
            )
        }.eraseToAnyView()
    }
```

I get an error as you can't make a binding from a computed property so make my own custom binding...

```
ForEach(viewModel.state.data.indicies, id: \.self) { index in
    DropdownView(viewModel: Binding<ItemViewModel>(
      get: {return viewModel.state.data[index] }, 
      set: { value in  
        var data = viewModel.state.data
        data[index] = value
        viewModel.state = .data(data)
      },
      isActionSheetPresented: $viewModel.isActionSheetPresented
    )
}
```

This works but are there any issues with setting the whole state again in the binding setter (I believe SwiftUI is intelligent enough that this would be efficient) or is there another way to do this here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my vision you mixed a state and a data, which are different things. So instead of `.data([T])`, I would recommend something like `.loaded` (ie, state) and keep data by standalone `@Published var data: [T]` property. If that adapted your code will look much more naturally.

Like

```
   ForEach(viewModel.data.indices, id: \.self) { index in
        DropdownView(
                viewModel: $viewModel.data[index],
                isActionSheetPresented: $viewModel.isActionSheetPresented
            )
        }//.eraseToAnyView()    // << you don't need this
    }
```

Comment: I think data with the type makes sense as part of the view state enum however I'm finding generally modelling view state as an enum with SwiftUI doesn't play that nicely when you have associated values